# Stream audio from android to PC

Tags: audio, music

I don't have a place to connect a cable on my phone. I would like to stream to pc where I can enjoy the audio on the big Headphones that connect via cable.
PC does not have bluetooth.
thanks

Comment: USB Bluetooth dongles are very cheap, therefore I would try this way first.